# Blending images and a mask with OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, blending

Given the following images:

original.png:
[image: original.png]

background.png:
[image: background.png]

mask.png:
[image: mask.png]

I'd like to blend them into the following (result.png):

[image: result.png]

I already know how to do this with Python PIL, but how do I do it with Python OpenCV?

Here is the Python PIL code for reference:

```
from PIL import Image

original = Image.open('original.png').convert('RGB')
background = Image.open('background.png').convert('RGB')
mask = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L')
result = Image.composite(original, background, mask)
result.save('result.png')
```

Can somebody help me fill in the following?:

```
import cv2

original = cv2.imread('original.png')
background = cv2.imread('background.png')
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png', 0)
result = ???? # What to do here?
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution that I know in Python/OpenCV/Numpy is to use Numpy where. This uses original where the mask is white and the background where the mask is black. If mask is not made grayscale, (i.e. kept 3 channel), then

```
result = np.where(mask==(255,255,255), original.png, background.png)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works for the example I provided.  Let me throw in a new problem though: What if the mask isn't strictly black and white?  I.E., let's say I want to apply a blur filter to the mask so that the transition between the original image and background image is more gradual.

Comment: You can do that by simply multiplying the mask with one image (and divide by 255) and the inverse mask with the other image (and divide by 255) and then adding the two (and multiply by 255). But you have to convert to float images, then at the end convert back to uint8.

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding or that still isn't quite right.  Here's my code:

    original = cv2.imread('original.png').astype(np.float64)
    background = cv2.imread('background.png').astype(np.float64)
    mask = cv2.imread('mask.png')
    mask = cv2.blur(mask, (5, 5))
inv_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask).astype(np.float64)
mask = mask.astype(np.float64)

    img1 = mask * original / 255.0
    img2 = inv_mask * background / 255.0
    result = ((img1 + img2) * 255.0).astype(np.uint8)
    cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)

Comment: Nevermind :). I figured out what was wrong.  Your answer was correct.  I was using numpy multiply and add when I needed to use cv2.multiply() and cv2.add().

Comment: Correct. Or simply do it in Python

Answer (score 2):

Answer courtesy of @fmw42:

```
import cv2
original = cv2.imread('original.png').astype(np.float64)
background = cv2.imread('background.png').astype(np.float64)
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png')
mask = cv2.blur(mask, (5, 5))
inv_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask).astype(np.float64)
mask = mask.astype(np.float64)
img1 = cv2.multiply(mask, original) / 255.0
img2 = cv2.multiply(inv_mask, background) / 255.0
result = (cv2.add(img1, img2)).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).